# Drupal 6 will not use updated htaccess 301 information

Tags: 6, .htaccess

I'm not 100% sure that this is a Drupal problem, but I think there is any issue with my site not flushing the cache. I am trying to change a redirect. I was having some trouble with URL Redirect in the CMS, so I am using the .htaccess file directly. Previously I had set up

redirect 301 /renew https://OLDREDIRECT.com

I just changed that to

redirect 301 /renew https://NEWREDIRECT.com

However, no matter what I do, the site keeps redirecting to the old link.

I have flushed the cache in Drupal, I've flushed my own browser cache, and I even tried running cron, but it will not use the new redirect info in .htaccess.

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you editing the correct .htaccess only (the one present in the drupal root folder)?

Comment: Yep, I double checked. I even removed 2 backup .htaccess files that the original developer had in there (“.htaccess 2”, “.htaccessBACKUP”), and it didn’t help.

Is it possible that my ExpiresDefault time needs to run out first? I would have though that flushing browser cache, etc., would force the browser to find the new redirect rules.

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess shouldn't require any cache flushes, restarts of the server, etc. They should just take effect.

If you want to check to make sure that your editing the right file (and your not on a production server) you can always throw and invalid line in your .htaccess file. If it throws back a 500 error, your editing the right file and something is wrong somewhere in it, if it doesn't your're working on the wrong file.

Comment: Weird. Instead of using an invalid line, I added a test redirect, and it is working—with a catch. When I add 
Redirect 301 /renew3443 http://DIFFERENT_DOMAIN.com 
Then that link takes me to DIFFERENT_DOMAIN.com/?q=renew3443
I wasn’t expecting the query to show up in the final URL. Is something wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, it turns out the problem was with my URL. I had retained a “++++++” instead of using “%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B”

That fixed it.